# Spring Batch test configuration issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i'm trying to implement unit tests for my batch application and facing issues with Spring Batch configuration.

Current dependencies versions:

```
Spring Boot 3.0.4
Spring Batch 5.0.0
```

My job configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class BatchProcessor {
    public static final String PRE_PROCESS_STEP = "pre-process-step";

    @Autowired
    protected PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
    @Autowired
    protected JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired 
    protected JobRepository jobRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected JobExplorer jobs;

    protected String jobName;

    @Bean
    public Job runJob() throws Exception {
        return new JobBuilder(jobName, jobRepository)
            .start(preProcessStep())
            .next(processStep())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step preProcessStep() {
        return new StepBuilder(PRE_PROCESS_STEP, jobRepository)
            .tasklet(preProcess(null), transactionManager)
            .build();
    }

    protected Tasklet preProcess(@Value("#{jobParameters[inputfilename]}") String fileName) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@JdbcTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(BatchProcessor.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
//@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchProcessorTest {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
  
    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @Mock
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Mock
    private StepContribution stepContribution;

    @Mock
    private StepContext stepContext;

    @Mock
    private ChunkContext chunkContext;

    private JobParameters setupJobParameters(String fileName) {
        JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        paramsBuilder.addString("inputfilename", fileName);
        return paramsBuilder.toJobParameters();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenFileName_whenMatched_thenSuccess() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(BatchProcessor.PRE_PROCESS_STEP, setupJobParameters("XXX"));
    }
}
```

With this configuration my test fails with the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Referencing [Spring Boot 3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes), starting from Spring Batch 5.0.0 `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation "tell the auto-configuration to back off.

But when I add `@EnableBatchProcessing` back to `BatchProcessorTest` class it starts working, but fails later with:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
> SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?

I tried to configure datasource manually

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
            .build();
    }
}
```

```
@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "dataSource")
```

with no success.

I had no experience writing unit tests for Spring applications and have no idea how can I resolve these issues. Could someone advise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my mistake. I've added `@JdbcTest` annotation to resolve my `PlatformTransactionManager` bean issue before. Removed that annotation from my test class, added mock `PlatformTransactionManager` and removed `@EnableBatchProcessing`.

Final working version is:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig(BatchProcessor.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class BatchProcessorTest {
    @MockBean
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
  
    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @Mock
    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Mock
    private StepContribution stepContribution;

    @Mock
    private StepContext stepContext;

    @Mock
    private ChunkContext chunkContext;

    private JobParameters setupJobParameters(String fileName) {
        JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        paramsBuilder.addString("inputfilename", fileName);
        return paramsBuilder.toJobParameters();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenFileName_whenMatched_thenSuccess() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep(BatchProcessor.PRE_PROCESS_STEP, setupJobParameters("XXX"));
    }
}
```